# Live DVD burning under Linux

Tags: linux, streaming, dvd-burning

[A similar question has already been asked for the .NET platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768/sdk-for-writing-dvds) but I am on Debian Linux.

I am trying to find a solution for burning a video DVD directly from a camera attached to a capture card. The card outputs an MPEG-2 stream and I want to write it directly to a DVD disc without creating any intermediate files.

The reason is so that when the recording is finished, the DVD can be very quickly finalized and ejected.

I have been looking at commandline tools like cdrecord and dvdauthor but I don't think they can do this. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

As in a data-dvd or videodvd?
video dvd might need some work, data dvd however can easily be done by piping the output of mkisofs to growisofs.

[man growisofs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/growisofs) [man mkisofs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkisofs)
edit:
    mkisofs -r /media/cam/ | growisofs -Z /dev/dvd

Comment: I'm trying to get a video DVD to be played in a normal DVD player. I need to convert the MPEG-2 stream into proper DVD VOBs, write them to the disc and then somehow write the index files last.